# How to display a div's name with jquery and css

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I'm working in a WordPress theme, and sometimes I like to develop some sort of "CSS CHEAT SHEET" that when linked to the site, adds margins, borders and some other properties that allow me to see a more visual guide as where does the elements relate, their nesting divs, etc.

kinda like :

```
    #page::after { content: 'B ) - #page'; }
```

To get something that resembles to guidelines / grid / rulers; but only if I link my css.

For more simple projects, usually I just need to target the element id but with wordpress some div names depend on other functions...

So I would like to get the element id with jquery and then display it with css in a pseudo element.

Is that possible?

I ask about jquery, because I also use  "Styler" (https://github.com/mjrthemes/styler)  to explore in this way live projects before working on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use css only:

```
 #page::after { 
    content: attr(id) 'B ) - #page';
 }
```